# I am getting Confused with host bits and Subnet bits

Tags: cisco, network, subnet

So i am playing with Cisco CML. I made up a random address 3.0.0.0/8.
I wanted to split up that subnet into 4 subnets, So 2^2 = 4. I kinda got confused along the way. In my train of though if we use the formula 2^N on 3.0.0.0/8 that would equal 256 subnets is that Correct ,and Can you use it classful addresses ?

Comment: Classful networking is long dead. It died in 1993 with the introduction of CIDR. Please leave it dead and buried. Subnetting with two bits creates 2^2=4 subnets: 3.0.0.0/10, 3.64.0.0/10, 3.128.0.0/10 and 3.192.0.0/10. But please use one RFC 1918, RFC 5737 or public addresses that you own in your questions.

Comment: 2^8 is 256, so 3.0.0.0/8 is one 256th of *the entire IP address space*. In you want to split that further, into 4 equal-sized parts, you need an *additional* 2 bits (since 4=2^2) of prefix, so you'd use /10s (8+2=10).